# How do I go around this Zend_Form_Element_Select db error?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

When i use the `Zend_Form_Element_Select` elements with multioptions i get this error when i pass the selected value to `Zend_DB_Table` to insert into the db

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accounts_status ' in 'field list'
```

I have extracted some code snippets that i believe will go a long way into illustrating my problem.The *accounts_status* field **DOES** exist in my table

On my form construct have added the select element and options (I have left out the other elements)

```
    $optionsstatus = array(
                    'active' => 'active',
                    'pending' => 'pending'              
                    );
    $optionsrole = array(
                'guest' => 'guest',
                'user' => 'user',
                'writer' => 'writer',
                'admin' => 'admin'              
                );

    $status = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('accounts_status');
                     $status->setLabel('Status')
                    ->setRequired(true)             
                    ->addMultiOptions($optionsstatus);
    $role = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('accounts_role');
                     $role->setLabel('Role')
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addMultiOptions($optionsrole);
```

I use the *Zend_DB_table* to insert the post values from my controller

```
public function addaccount($username, $fullname, $email,
        $password,$status,$roles,$comments)
    {
        $data = array(
                'accounts_username' => $username,
                'accounts_fullname' => $fullname,
                'accounts_email' => $email,
                'accounts_password' => $password,               
                'accounts_status ' => $status,
                'accounts_roles' => $roles,             
                'accounts_comments ' => $comments,
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }
```

In my controller i get the post values and send them to my model

```
$username = $form->getValue('accounts_username');
                $fullname = $form->getValue('accounts_fullname');
                $email = $form->getValue('accounts_email');
                $password = $form->getValue('accounts_password');
                $status = $form->getValue('accounts_status');
                $roles = $form->getValue('accounts_roles');
                $comments = $form->getValue('accounts_comments');
                $accounts = new Model_DbTable_Account();
                $accounts->addaccount($username, $fullname,$email,
                $password,$status,$roles,$comments);
```

This approach works for me except when am dealing with the `Zend_Form_Element_Select` elements.Am just wondering if there is a specific way of dealing with this select elements when it comes to CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accounts_status ' in 'field list'
```

Maybe I'm crazy, but looks to me like there's an extra space on that end of that `'accounts_status '` field name.

Comment: How do I get rid of that because clearly I am not introducing those "spaces" anywhere in my code.

Comment: np. sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes :)